# Logging with aspects

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj

Have a RESTful web-serice with Facade layer, Service layer and Dao layer.
Trying to journalize all invokes of all methods of classes, marked with annotation @Log

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Log {
}
```

Here's the aspect code:

```
public class LoggingAspect {
  @Around("@target(Log)")
  public Object log(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
    log.debug("Start " + pjp.getSignature().getName());
    Object result = pjp.proceed();
    log.debug("End " + pjp.getSignature().getName());
    return result;
  }
}
```

Facade, Service and Dao are marked with @Log.
Some example:

```
public Obj Facade.createObj(String name){ //1
  return service.createObj(name);
}

public Obj Service.createObj(String name){ //2
  return dao.createObj(name);
}

public Obj Dao.createObj(String name){ //3
  Long idOfCreatedObj = /*code that creates an object and returns it's ID*/;
  return loadObjById(idOfCreatedObj); /* load the created object by id */
}

public Obj Dao.loadObjById(Long id){ //4
  return /* code that loads the object by it's id */;
}
```

In this example methods 1, 2, 3 are logged successfully. But the nested dao method (loadObjById) is not logged.

WHY?

P.S. In spring-config.xml there's
    `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>`

Comment: Has the loadObjById method the @log annotation?

Comment: What AOP implementation are you using? AspectJ weaving, or Spring's dynamic proxies? The latter doesn't work with non-public methods because they can't be proxied. (See the note in this section of the docs: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.5/reference/aop.html#aop-pointcuts-designators)

Comment: **jddsantaella**, yes, it has.

**millimoose**, I use Spring's dynamic proxies. And all these methods are public.

Comment: If I call loadObjById from Facade (by chain, instead of createObj), everything's fine. But when Dao method call other Dao method, the other methods aren't logged.

Comment: The problem is when in Dao method other Dao method is invoked. Or in Service method other Service method is invoked.

Comment: @omickron It doesn't matter whether they're public or not (I phrased it badly), but whether you're calling the method "through" the proxy. Because this proxy is a wrapper that ultimately delegates to your classes, `this` in your code is never an instance of the proxy, and thus won't invoke the aspects. (You can easily verify all this with a debugger.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is self calls (`this.methodcall()`) bypass the dynamic/cglib proxy that is created by Spring to handle the cross cutting concern.

The fix is either to use full Aspectj (compile time or load time weaving) or make the call by getting hold of the proxy (instead of alling `this.methodCall()`, use `proxy.methodCall()`

You can get hold of the proxy this way:

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy expose-proxy="true"/>
```

And in your code:  `AopContext.currentProxy()` will give you a reference to the proxy. Here is one blog article on this if you are interested - http://www.java-allandsundry.com/2012/07/reference-to-dynamic-proxy-in-proxied.html

Comment: Can you tell me, how to use full Aspectj (compile time or load time weaving)? What do you mean?

Comment: @omickron I think how to set up load time weaving should be mentioned in the Spring docs. (There should also be many blog posts about it on the Web.) AspectJ weaving is a process wherein your class files are *modified in place* (while on disk, or during loading) to add the code of the aspects into the intercepted methods. (As opposed to creating entirely different proxy classes wrapping yours.)

Comment: Great answer Biju Kunjummmen! But I'm wondering.. it is possible to configure <aop:aspectj-autoproxy expose-proxy="true" /> using only annotations?